# Как можно реализовать правильное автозаполнение input`ов номера телефона и пароля

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Нужно реализовать такую функцию:
Есть инпут "Номер телефона"
Есть инпут "Пароль"
Если пользователь копирует одновременно логин и пароль в виде (+7(999)999-99-99 qwerty) или (+7999-999-99-99                    qwerty) или (79  99)99 9999 qwerty и т.д),нужно повесить на обработчик onPaste такую функцию,которая сможет обрабатывать данные из буфера обмена и при вставке из буфера обмена автоматически  заполнять поле телефона и пароля,то есть убирая все пробелы,скобочки и плюсы в номере телефона и приводя телефон к виду 79209309292

```
onPasteAutorize = (e) => {
        const subArr = e.clipboardData.getData('text').trim().split(/\s+/)
            setTimeout(()=>{
                const subStr = subArr.join("").replace(/\+/,'').replace(/\(/,'').replace(/\)/,'')
                const login = subStr.substring(0,11)
                const password = subStr.substring(11)
                this.onLoginChange(login)
                this.onPasswordChange(password)
            },100)
        e.preventDefault()
    }
```

Есть такой код,но проблема в том,что если копировать номер без + и (),то он убирает их из пароля(если они там присутствуют)
Направьте,пожалуйста,на путь истинный!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если в два этапа?

```
str = "7922-234-56-78 MySupErPuPERpa55woRD"
pNum = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'').substring(0,11); // Удаляем все символы, которые не являются цифрами и берем первые 11 символов.
sep = pNum.slice(-1) + " "; / Разделитель - последняя цифра номера и пробел.
pwd = str.split(sep);
pwd = pwd[1];
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!Помогло)

Comment: Хотя не совсем правильно работает, если в пароле цифры совпадающие с цифрами в номере телефона, то split()в итоге разделяет пароль

Comment: Спит делит по сепаратору, а он в примере "8 " т.е. и в пароле должен быть пробел. А в паролях не должно быть пробелов.

Comment: Можно делить строку по пробелу и брать последний элемент массива. т.к. в номере телефона пробелы допустимы, а паролях нет. pwd = str.split(" ").pop();